# Run python code from PHP page on beaglebone

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I'm trying to run the code bellow from a PHP page on my beaglebone black:

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.PWM as PWM

red = "P8_13"
green = "P8_19"
blue = "P9_14"

PWM.start(red, 0)
PWM.start(blue, 0)
PWM.start(green, 0)

PWM.set_duty_cycle(red, 100)
PWM.set_duty_cycle(green, 0)
PWM.set_duty_cycle(blue, 0)
```

This code is just to turn my RGB LED to red.

My PHP page bellow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>RGB LED</title>
</head>
<body>
Testing led.py execution...<br>
<?php

exec( "python led.py" );

?>
<br>End of execution!<br>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using Apache2 and PHP5.

The code is on the same path of PHP page ("/var/www"). I already tried exec, shell_exec and system commands to execute the script. The LED doesn't turn to red. The code already have 777 permission. I really don't know why it isn't working. Does anyone have any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: do you get any error messages?  are you logging in debug mode?

Comment: on many systems `Apache` runs as `www-data` user with different permissions and with different environment variables than normal user.

Comment: Thank you @furas. I gave permission to www-data on sudoers file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really want to go deep with this problem. But I am writing you this because I once played with a BBB and had a funny permission error while running python scripts. I was running commands without `sudo`. Please try it. I don't why it should have a `sudo` but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Thank you @furas.
I added "www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/python" to the sudoers file and also changed exec("python led.py") to exec ("sudo python led.py").